# Issue adding a unique ID to an HTML attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am having an issue changing the ID of HTML attributes using JQuery.

This is what I have been using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.hiddenDiv').each(function (i) {
            $(this).attr("id", "title" + (i + 1));
        });
```

This the HTML:

```
<div id="Foo">

    <div class="title"></div>
    <hr></hr>
    <div class="hiddenDiv" style="display:none;"></div>
    <hr></hr>
    <div class="title"></div>
    <hr></hr>
    <div class="hiddenDiv" style="display:none;"></div>

</div>
```

I am producing the HTML using another JQuery script that creates it, iterating through an object creating a **title** and **hiddenDiv** divs for each element that exists in the object.

jQuery Script that produces the HTML:

```
 $('#Foo').append('<div class="hiddenDiv" style="display:none;">' + foo[0].Content + '<br>' + 'Address: ' + foo[0].Address + '</div><br><hr>');
```

Both scripts execute when the document is ready.

Comment: If the `.hiddenDiv` are appended from a loop you can add this direclty to the produced HTML.

Comment: Side note: I'd avoid using `<br/><hr/>` use CSS `bottom-border`, `margin` and `padding` to achive the same result.

Comment: @JonP Good point, I am just trying to do a proof of concept :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like elements are not created on DOM ready. You need to add the ids to them just after appending the content. like this:

```
$('#Foo').append('<div class="hiddenDiv" style="display:none;">' + foo[0].Content + '<br>' + 'Address: ' + foo[0].Address + '</div><br><hr>');
$('.hiddenDiv').each(function (i) {
        $(this).attr("id", "title" + (i + 1));
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gc9Ny/)**

Comment: Awesome that works. However are you not better off separating out the logic?

Comment: That wont get applied to this. imagine doing something to elements that have not got created yet.

Comment: Okay that makes sense and was what I originally thought, however I got hung up on separating out the logic. Thanks for your help!